# Vuex - is it a good idea to ignore mutation handlers and always mutate the store data directly?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using mutation handlers requires you to write hundreds of times more code compared to direct mutations (in large apps, if you follow official guidelines) because they require computed properties and store mutations for every nested state property.

I know that not using mutation handlers, in theory, makes it more difficult to track down the source of some errors, but in practice, if there's only a few functions that change a specific state property, it's pretty easy to determine which one of them caused the error by following the event logic because mutations are in most cases caused by some sort of known event (button press, input change, etc), so when an error appears during a specific event, it's not that difficult to track down the function that caused it, without using mutation handlers anyway.

The question is what do you actually lose if all components mutate store data directly without using mutation handlers (except debugging)?

Like this, for example:

#### `App.vue`

```html
<v-btn @click="createNewItem({ type: 'file', extension: 'txt' })">
  Create new item
</v-btn>
```

```js
methods: {
  createNewItem (params) {
    // Set dialog data
    this.$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.data = { 
      ...this.$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.data,
      ...params 
    }
    // Open dialog
    this.$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.isOpened = true
  }
}
```

#### `Dialogs.vue`

```html
<v-dialog v-model="$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.isOpened">
  <div class="title">
    Create new {{$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.data.type}}
  </div>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="createNewItemDialog.data.name"
  />
  <v-btn @click="$store.state.dialogs.createNewItemDialog.isOpened = false">
    close dialog
  </v-btn>
</v-dialog>
```

```js
// NO COMPUTED PROPERTIES NEEDED
```

#### `store.js`

```js
state = {
  dialogs: {
    createNewItemDialog: {
      value: false,
      data: {
        type: 'file',
        name: '',
        extension: ''
      }
    } 
  }
}

// NO MUTATIONS AND ACTIONS NEEDED
```

Answer (score 1):

As I remember we got error in production when we accidentally let a direct references to a variable in $store, I don't remember what was the real problem anyway, maybe it was only a coincidence.

Another reason to use mutations to handle change of state in one place. If you have "side effect" you can handle this, e.g: if you delete one of your state property whick can indicate to delete another one or recalculate something.

Comment: Yeah, you will get the mutation error if you don't set `strict: false` in store.js config object, but that's expected, I'm trying to figure out if it's actually necessary to use mutations handlers or if it's just a "preferred way" to mutate data. I understand your point about mutating relevant properties, but I can do that with direct mutations as well. What I don't know is whether I can just avoid mutation handlers completely and always mutate store data directly.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is what do you actually lose if all components mutate store data directly without using mutation handlers (except debugging)?

You will loose vue-devtools Vuex debugging information. Updates won't appear there.

The question could be. What do you actually need?
If it is a reactive global `dialogs` state that you need. Then you can use it like that.

But then maybe Vuex might be an overkill for the purpose.

Comment: I'm developing a big app, so I have to use Vuex actions for some complex mutations, but when it comes to smaller mutations, like in the example, I'm considering switching to direct mutations, so I don't have to create 10 computed properties and 10 store mutations for every dialog's nested property or create a generator that dynamically creates those computed properties and mutations. But my question is - what functionality I will lose when I move to direct mutations, will everything work the same, except debugging becoming more difficult?

Comment: One thing I could find you will lose is this: vue-devtools Vuex debugging information. Updates won't appear there.

Comment: Yeah, If that's all I loose, then that's a very good tradeoff to make since direct mutations make components much cleaner. To use mutation handlers I have to have a separate computed property + a store mutation (according to Vuex's official guidelines) for every nested property of every state property, which takes thousands of lines of code if you don't create a computed / mutation property generator

Answer (score 0):

You will loose perspective. Your application might be simple now, but that may change in future as you will be adding new features.

You already mentioned some pros of mutations. So if it's long term project, then those extra lines might be worth it.